Spark SQL Streaming Join & pivot one to many joined records using joined key
I have 2 streaming data in Kafka topic, I have to join
Stream1.join(Stream2) on common key and I have already applied watermark and window for both stream at event timestamp field. I can see joined results as well,
but use case scenario is,
If I get joined 1 to many records (DataFrame), I have to pivot them into one record right after join
Stream1
|Name |  Standard | Eventtime
|XXX  |  SSLC    |  2024-05-05:09:30:00AM
|YYY  |  HSC      | 2024-05-04:09:35:00AM
Stream 2
|Name |subject | Eventtime
|XXX | Sub1  |   2024-05-05:10:15:00AM
|XXX | Sub2  |   2024-05-05:10:15:00AM
|XXX | Sub3   |  2024-05-05:10:15:00AM
|YYY | Sub1   |  2024-05-05:10:15:00AM
|YYY | Sub2  |   2024-05-05:10:15:00AM
|YYY | Sub3   |  2024-05-05:10:15:00AM
|YYY | Sub4  |   2024-05-05:10:15:00AM
Step 1: joinedDF = Stream1.join(stream2).on("Name")
Step 2: joinedDF.groupBy("Name").pivot("Subject")
Result:
XXX |Sub1 |Sub2 |Sub3
YYY| Sub1| Sub2 |Sub3 |Sub4
I understood multiple aggregation not supported during at step2
What are best ways to implement this as stateful spark streaming (single)job.

Use the process of handling multiple records per key. One way to achieve this is by starting with windowing, applying a UDF, and then pivoting the subjects into columns.
